# indexing types in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j

I've always worked with SQL where it has several type of indexes:
(Clustered, Nonclustered, Unique, Full Text, Spatial and others).

Now I'm getting my feet wet with Neo4J and I was asking myself (after reading [this](http://nigelsmall.com/neo4j/index-confusion)) if **Schema Indexes** and **Legacy Indexes** are the only existing indexes in Neo4J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index types that are built into neo4j are `schema` and `legacy`, as you have found. However, you can create a plugin or unmanaged extension that implements its own indexing.

For example, there is a [Neo4j Spatial plugin](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial) that implements spatial indexes.